# React Native FlatList rendering a few items at a time

Tags: react-native

I have a list of chat messages in my app to which new items are added to the bottom. I used some code from another SO question to make the FlatList stick to the bottom when new items are added, as below

```
<FlatList
    data={messages}
    renderItem={({item}) => <ChatMessage message={item}></ChatMessage>}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    initialNumToRender={messages.length}
    initialScrollIndex={messages.length-1}
    ref={ref => this.flatList = ref}
    onContentSizeChange={(contentWidth, contentHeight)=>{        
        this.flatList.scrollToEnd();
    }}

/>
```

The problem is that when the initial list renders (only 35 items, hardcoded in an array for now) it seems to render just a few items, then scroll down a bit, then render a few more, then scroll down a bit until it finally completes the rendering and sticks to the bottom. It's choppy and slow, despite adding initialNumToRender={messages.length} and rendering an incredibly simple  node for each result.

Ideally I guess I need to wait for it to fully render before displaying anything to the user but (A) they'd have to wait a couple of seconds to start using the chat room and (B) I don't think that's how Flatlist works, I assume the elements have to be viewable before it is rendered.

Is there just a better way to do this? (Testing on Android by the way)

EDIT: Adding ChatMessage component for completeness

```
// Chat Message
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import { 
    StyleSheet,
    ImageBackground,
    Text,
    View
} from 'react-native'

class ChatMessage extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {  }
    }

    render() { 
        return (
            <View style={styles.chatMessage}>

                <View style={styles.chatMessage_layout}>

                    <View style={styles.chatMessage_pic}>
                        <View style={styles.chatMessage_pic_image}>
                            <ImageBackground 
                                source={require('./assets/images/profile-pics/example-profilr.png')} 
                                style={styles.chatMessage_pic_image_background}
                                imageStyle={{ borderRadius: 40/2 }}
                                resizeMode="cover"
                            >
                            </ImageBackground>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.chatMessage_details}>
                        <View style={styles.chatMessage_name}>
                            <Text style={styles.chatMessage_name_text}>
                                {this.props.message.name}
                                <Text style={styles.chatMessage_name_time}>  24h</Text>
                            </Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.chatMessage_message}>
                            <Text style={styles.chatMessage_message_text}>{this.props.message.text}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>

                </View>

            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default ChatMessage;


const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    chatMessage: {
        paddingVertical: 10,
        paddingHorizontal: 24
    },

    chatMessage_layout: {
        flexDirection: 'row'
    },

    chatMessage_pic: {
        width: 40,
        height: 40,
        marginRight: 12
    },

    chatMessage_pic_image: {
        width: 40,
        height: 40
    },

    chatMessage_pic_image_background: {
        width: 40,
        height: 40
    },

    chatMessage_details: {
        flex: 1
    },

    chatMessage_name_text: {
        color: '#FFF',
        fontSize: 14,
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    },

    chatMessage_name_time: {
        fontSize: 11,
        color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.6)'
    },

    chatMessage_message: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },

    chatMessage_message_text: {
        color: '#FFF',
        fontSize: 12
    }

})
```

Comment: Can you also post your `ChatMessage` component?

Comment: In https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat, he uses list to render from bottom to top.

Comment: Added sub-component

Comment: Thanks @Kranthi , will look into that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have *less* number of items and want to render *all* items at once then you should use [`ScrollView`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#props) as mentioned in the [**docs**](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#props)

**ScrollView**: Renders all elements at once, but slow if there are *large number of elements*.

**FlatList**: Renders items in a **lazy** mode, when they are *about to appear* and removes them when they leave the *visible display* to save memory that makes it usable for performance on large lists.

For Flatlist *optimization* you need to use `PureComponent` whenever you render the child so that it only [*shallow compares the props*](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent).

Also in the `keyExtractor` use a *unique id* for your `item` and do not depend upon the `index`, since when the item updates the `index` is not reliable and may change

Comment: Thanks Pritish, I wonder what a "large number" could mean? I probably won't allow more then 100. I seem to have found that inverted="true" seems to be working and rendering the list from the bottom up, which is not what I expected it to do from the limited description in the docs (I just have to reverse the order of my array). I'll accept your answer as correct, not sure if you want to add anything about inverted="true" for people who may come across this answer?

Comment: A large number would be around `1000`, I just wanted to highlight the default behaviour of `Flatlist` and `ScrollView` and the use of `PureComponent` which should massively improve the performance. The rest are cosmetic changes.